# Store an array to WordPress database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, wordpress

I created an application that's hosted in a WordPress website that allows everything on the page to be customized. How can I store an array with a user-defined ID to the WordPress database when the user clicks Save? The user can then go to their "Customized Pages" page and view all of their customized pages named as the ID they set when initially saving. On clicking on one of their customized pages, it will load the customizable page with the array associated to the ID that they set.

Edit

Gone with the JSON Encode method. Here is where i am at.

```
var array = [];

$('img').click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 array.push(id);

});

$('#sendQuote').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  url:"readJson.php",
  method: "post",
  data: { myBuild: JSON.stringify( array ) },
  success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
})
});
```

ReadJson.php

```
$array = $_POST['myBuild'];
print_r($array);

global $wpdb;
```

Any ideas in posting this to wp_meta or a custom table?

Comment: Author Meta or options table should be fine. Custom tables have other advantages and I've used them a lot. Just figure out what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

Encode the array as json using `json_encode` and then decode it for use using `json_decode`

Serialize the array via `serialize` and unserialize via `unserialize`

Comment: Doing that would make it impossible to query for certain items in the array. Sure you could pull everything out and then filter but its not as efficient. Also those aren't the only options... probably the most accepted way is to store each item in its own table.

Comment: You can absolutely do queries against strong json depending on the data you are searching. You can't index values but you can search values. It depends on what you need, in this case it sounds like a collection of configuration variables which is not often a set of values you need to query.

Comment: Well, it **really** depends on the database. I know with with ms sql at least, json is stored as plain text, therefore losing the ability to query and search field values.

Comment: We're talking about mysql or mariadb because it's WordPress. But again you can query the DB for strings inside the JSON, and again in the example provided by the request he doesn't need to query values anyway. They are just storing configuration.

Comment: *you can query the DB for strings inside the JSON*.... and thats about all you can do. You cant say anything like "give me objects in this array whos values equal this". Idk about mariadb but mysql is this way as well, you have to store json as plain text. Yeah I get that its easy to just get the entire string, but with large data sets storing as json would be a nightmare.

Comment: You are still fretting over an invalid use case, the response was based in the question specifics. If the question was worried about query power I would have different recommendations.

Comment: The question was *how to store an array in a sql database*, I say sql because the question is tagged sql. I was not wrong in saying that you cannot store arrays in sql databases, because you can't. You're right though, storing plain text json is a solution for their problem, but not the question they asked.